# Removing a fragment from the same container

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments added to stage in one and the same container. Two fragments are added with `addToBackStack` method:

```
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And final one is added without back stack:

```
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

All three co-exist fine because as I understand if a fragment is added using a backstack, then it's not destroyed when another fragment is added.
The last one is added without a backstack, meaning that once I call `replace` it should be destroyed.

However, this does not happen and when I call

```
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, myNewFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I can still see that there are 4 fragments total in my `R.id.container`, which is not that I expect.

How can I make my 3rd fragment disappear when I call `replace` method when adding 4th fragment?

Answer (score 1):

> By calling addToBackStack(), the replace transaction is saved to the
>   back stack so the user can reverse the transaction and bring back the
>   previous fragment by pressing the Back button.

So in your case you are replacing the third fragment with the fourth fragment . It means for reversing the transaction they need fragment3 also . So they will not destroy it.

Comment: by why `replace` does not actually replace fragment? For instance once I have my first fragment added, why doesn't the second `replace` call remove it from the list?

Comment: Actually it is removing from the view , but it will be inside the fragment manager . So that we can use the same instance.